# Safe way to programmatically move a batch of file?

Tags: c#, file, filesystems, .net

What does one need to take care of when creating a method to move (cut) a batch of file from one directory to another?

Let's say the method signature is `Move(filter, sourceFolder, destinationFolder, overwrite)`. What do I need to take care of to avoid the risk of data loss especially when overwriting the original file and deleting of the source file is taken into account?

Several possible scenario I am worried of: error occurs when a move is in progress, moved a file but the file are somehow corrupted, deleted a namesake file in order to allow the new file to move but then error happens when moving the new file, etc.

I'm using .net's System.IO namespace for the move operations.

Comment: Are you able to use transactions?

Comment: Here's a description of transactional NTFS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163388.aspx

Comment: Gabe: does that only work on Vista and later?

Comment: My program has to also work with XP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without transactions, the safest way is to copy, verify and then delete. It is up to you if you want to move per file (this is how windows does it, a move operation can fail leaving you with half of the files moved) or to allow only the entire batch to be moved, or none at all.

You would have to make decisions on how to respond to files that have been modified during the move, source files that cannot be deleted afterwards, or destination files that have already been opened when you're performing a rollback.

Comment: IMO, a drawback of this approach is that a copy is slower than a move (usually instant)

Comment: True, but without some kind of transactions, rolling back a partially succeeded move can get tricky. Not that "my" move method guarantees a clean move or rollback - it just guarantees that either the entire move succeeds, or fails but leaving the source files untouched.